# Como hacer un instalador de un proyecto con base de datos de Sql server, que sirva en cualquier pc

Tags: c#

por favor saquenme un problemon, lo que pasa es que realize un proyecto Visual en c# en visual studio 2017, con una base de datos para un Login, en donde todo iva bien, hasta que realize el instalador, y me di cuenta que no se incluia la base de datos. como puedo hacer para que la base vaya dentro del paquete de instalacion y que funcione sin contra tiempos en cualquier pc?
Una cosa mas, no tengo instalado Sql server como tal, la base la cree dentro visual studio(dejo la captura abajo)
Soy principiante, es la primera vez que realizo algo asi, y esto es para mañana, ayuda por favor!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si estás usando para el proyecto de instalación la herramienta de Microsoft, en los requisitos puedes indicarle que te instale SQL Server, y en las acciones post instalación ejecutar una restauración de la base de datos, tendrías que añadir una copia vacía de tu base de datos, y tendrías que tener en cuenta la cadena de conexión que cambiará

Answer (score 0):

Si es urgente te recomendaria que hagas la misma bd que tienes en SQL Server pero en Access, no tendrias que cambiar las consultas del programa si creas las mismas tablas y relaciones en access, si vas a generar un instalador y el .exe va a estar junto a la bd en access .accdb en la conexion pondrias en la cadena :

```
    Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BaseDeDatos.accdb;
```

Además, tu archivo es .mdf, si fuera .sdf podrias administrar una version portable con SQL Server Compact, porque si estas usando SQL Express Local DB tendrias que instalar y restaurar la bd en el cliente y no es algo conveniente, puedes fijarte si usas Local DB yendo al menu inicio y buscando Visual Studio Installer en Cargas de trabajo a la derecha en Detalles de instalacion extiendes la flecha que dice Desarollo de Escritorio .NET al final de Opcional dice SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB, ese es una version mas ligera de sql server que no es portable como la version Compact.
Te recomiendo que empieces haciendo la misma bd en access y cambiando la cadena de conexion como mencione o buscar otra forma, asi te aseguras que siempre el archivo de access ira en la instalacion.
Saludos

Comment: Sí ha usado entity framework para el acceso a datos, la solución que indicas creo que no le vale